# How to create streaming Web api? or which techonology we can implement to create streaming api in .NET?

Tags: .net, api, webapi

I need API which stream live data to UI (UI might be react or angular application). Once I call the server, it should keep on giving live data in JSON format. For eg application like Blotter screen in Trading application

Which technology will be more suitable to create this type of API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at WebSockets and ASP.NET Core SignalR

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

The [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr) would be the most convenient technology to use.